# TarArchive Hangs When Trying to Extract Contents

Tags: c#, .net, tar, sharpziplib

I'm trying to create a tar archive, then extract all the contents to a file using [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib). I am able to create the tar archive, but the program hangs when trying to extract it. I'm wondering if anyone else can reproduce this problem and see why it is happening. I've also tried using [an example that allows for full control](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/GZip-and-Tar-Samples#extractFull), and while debugging, it seems that my program hangs when `tarIn.GetNextEntry()` is called.

Here is my code

```
public void CreateTarAndExtract()
        {
            // create tar file
            string tarFile = "path_to_desktop\\tartest.tar";
            string inputFolder = "path_to_desktop\\testfolder";
            using (var output = File.OpenWrite(tarFile))
            {
                using (var archive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(output, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var trimLength = inputFolder.Length + 1;

                    foreach (var fsEntry in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(inputFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {
                        var entry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(fsEntry);
                        entry.Name = fsEntry.Substring(trimLength);
                        archive.WriteEntry(entry, false);
                    }
                }
            }

            // extract file
            string outputPath = "path_to_desktop\\tartest";
            using (var input = File.OpenRead(tarFile))
            {
                using (var archive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(input, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    archive.ExtractContents(outputPath);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I reproduced your code and I have exactly the same result, the application freezes, I'm trying to fix the problem

Comment: FYI: .NET 7 provides tar-related functions in the [System.Formats.Tar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.tar?view=net-7.0) namespace. Although there is no final release of .NET 7 yet, a release candidate is available if you are interested in trying the System.Formats.Tar stuff out...

Comment: Async bug, don't call this on the main thread of a GUI app.

Comment: @HansPassant yes it looks like that was the issue. I ran it in a different thread and it worked perfectly! Feel free to make an answer and I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I get to unpack the tar archive this way:

```
    // extract file
    string outputPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "tartest");
    using (var input = File.OpenRead(tarFile))
    {
        ExtractTar(input, outputPath);
    }
```

---

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extractes a <c>tar</c> archive to the specified directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The <i>.tar</i> to extract.</param>
    /// <param name="outputDir">Output directory to write the files.</param>
    public static void ExtractTar(Stream stream, string outputDir)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[100];
        while (true)
        {
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, 100);
            var name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0');
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                break;
            stream.Seek(24, SeekOrigin.Current);
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, 12);
            var size = Convert.ToInt64(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, 12).Trim('\0').Trim(), 8);

            stream.Seek(376L, SeekOrigin.Current);

            var output = Path.Combine(outputDir, name);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(output)))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(output));
            if (!name.Equals("./", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                using (var str = File.Open(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    var buf = new byte[size];
                    stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    str.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                }
            }

            var pos = stream.Position;

            var offset = 512 - (pos % 512);
            if (offset == 512)
                offset = 0;

            stream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Current);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this also solved my problem! However, I believe that HansPassant's comment that clarified it was an async bug solved the problem in a simpler way, so I will be accepting his answer once he posts it.